# Building a web application without server side web technology like asp.net, asp.net mvc etc

Tags: jquery, html, mono, client-server, client-side

I have requirement of a small web application, which has to collect some data like customer information, customer's job details etc. I just want to process the data at client side and after that send that data to server side using ajax call, to store that in some DB e.g. Sql Server.
I decided to go with HTML5, JQuery at client side, at server side I will have web service to interact with my database (most probably WCF or ASP.NET web services), the web services will be consumed by JQuery AJAX calls. To expose services I will use mono.
Now my questions are,

> How should I create a master page or layout page with only html, javascript/jquery and css
> to persist common things like navigation menu etc.?
>
> How to load different pages with master page menu so the Url is bookmark-able?
>
> Is it possible to submit the html form at client side only? so when user click submit button, the page will be submitted to a client side file and data will be processed by that file, if needed will be saved to DB with ajax call to web service?
> if this is possible, how to handle submitted form using a jquery file?

It would be great help if anyone could suggest about the approach/technology/way to proceed, if I should change my approach or if any improvements i can make by using any other open source technology.
I think, I asked lot of things, but small suggestions and directions would also be great help.

Comment: How are you gonig to make web services with "no web technology"?

Comment: Do you truly want no server-side technology?  Or do you simply want to not store any data server-side?  You can store data client-side and still use stuff on the server, such as includes and minification.

Comment: Where will you store the data exactly?

Comment: You're going to have trouble persisting data.

Comment: Also, many browsers will object to using cross-domain AJAX calls. And they will have to be cross-domain in your current setup, because you can't run the web services on your own server.

Comment: Wait, open source is OK? So you can use PHP or MONO?

Comment: I want to store data in Database only such as Sql server or MySql and I dont want to install asp.net engine or any other server side technology engine on my web server

Comment: I am thinking to use mono for web services

Comment: Again, where will you store the data? Where is the database? On the server? Or on the user's own client computer? If the latter, you don't need a web app.

Comment: I will store the data on the server not on user's machine. DB will be on web server, which is separate machine..not the client(user's) machine.

Answer (score 1):

There are some old sites I've worked on that use iframes to simulate master pages (master pages didn't exist yet).

You should be able to do something similiar

You could also look into using a front end javascript framework like backbone.js or knockout. There's allot of neat ones out there.

**EDIT**

After thinking about it for a bit, I think knockout.js might work best for you.

Comment: He's not going to be able to persist data.

Comment: That's a very brittle solution. What happens when they clear cookies?

Comment: I think knockout.js is good suggestion, i would try to use it. though I need to explore it.

Comment: Knockout.js would be a great way to do this.